# What to change in my code to calculate sample Standard deviation instead of population standard deviaiton?

Tags: java, math, standard-deviation

My code calculates the population deviation when I need it to calculate the sample deviation I have compared both formulas and tried changed my calculations but nothing seems to work. Thanks for everyone's help or input in advance.

```
public class MeanAndStandardDeviation {
public static void main (String argv []) throws IOException {
    BufferedReader stdin =
            new BufferedReader (new InputStreamReader (System.in));
    NumberFormat nf = new DecimalFormat ("0.00");
    nf.setMinimumFractionDigits (2);//Sets Min digits
    nf.setMaximumFractionDigits (2);//Sets Max digits
    String inputValue;
    int count = 0;
    //For Loop for count
    for(int i = 0; i < count; i++){
        count++;
    }
    double varianceFinal = 0;
    List<String> input = new ArrayList<String>();//String ArrayList
    List<Double> numbers = new ArrayList<Double>();//Double ArrayList

  //While loop that takes in all my input and assigns it to the ArrayLists
  //Parameters set for when null is entered and total numbers go over 500
    while((inputValue = stdin.readLine()) != null && !inputValue.equals("") && input.size()<500){//Parameters set for when null is entered and total numbers go over 500
        input.add(inputValue);
        numbers.add (Double.parseDouble(inputValue));  
    }

System.out.println ("Standard Deviation: " +(nf.format(calcStdDev (numbers, count, varianceFinal))));//Prints the Standard Deviation
}

//StandardDeviation Class
static double calcStdDev (List<Double> numbers, int count, double variance){
    variance = 0;
    double sum = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < numbers.size(); i++){
        sum += numbers.get(i);
        variance += numbers.get(i) * numbers.get(i);
        count++;
    }
    double varianceFinal = ((variance/count)-(sum*sum)/(count*count));
return Math.sqrt(varianceFinal);

}
}
```

Comment: By the way my Standard Deviation Class is at the bottom

Comment: Just for the record: be precise about naming: you have two static **methods** there, not classes.

Comment: You could, by comparing the code, just simply say `calcStdDev = sqrt(calcVariance)`. -- You are implementing the biased estimator. When estimating both mean and variance simultaneously, the unbiased variance estimator is `varianceFinal = (variance-(sum*sum)/count) /(count-1)`.

Comment: Thank you I really appreciate the help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seriously, your code is "wrong" on many levels. So instead of debugging all of that for you, I will give you some hints how to **fix** and simplify your code - then it should be very easy for you to fix/resolve your actual math problem.

First of all, your code is so written in a confusing style that just makes it **much** harder to understand (and therefore *debug*) than it needs to be.

Example:

```
int count = 0;
//For Loop for count
for(int i = 0; i < count; i++){
    count++;
}
```

That for loop doesn't do *anything*. And even when the condition would be something else, like `i < someNumber`; you would still just need to put `count = someNumber` there; instead of looping!

Same here: what is the point of providing **count** as argument to your calc methods?! And to then just increase it? So, lets rewrite that:

```
public static double calcStdDev (List<Double> numbers, double variance) {
  double sumOfNumbers = 0;
  double sumOfSquares = 0;
  for(double number : numbers) {
    sumOfNumbers += number;
    sumOfSquares += number * number;
}
... and instead of calculating count, you simply have
int numberOfNumbers = numbers.size();
... and now, do your math
```

The other thing that is really strange in your code is how you setup your *variance* variable; and how it is used within your calc methods.

Long story short: step back and remove everything from your code that isn't required.

Comment: Thank you for your advice and help sorry it was so bad :(

Comment: You are welcome. I hope that my thoughts get you in the right direction; and are enough to finally resolve your issue.

Comment: Yeah it did, again thanks again and sorry it was so bad I'm still learning

Comment: No problem. If you are think you are "good to go", please consider accepting my answer; to make it clear that you are not looking for more input from other folks.

Answer (score 0):

It is a bad idea to compute the variance as you do. If the mean is largeish, eg 10 million, and the noise is smallish, eg around 1 then the limited precision of doubles may well mean that your computed variance is negative and the the sd will be nan.

You should either compute it in two passes, eg

```
double mean = 0.0;
   for( i=0; i<n; ++i)
   {  mean += x[i];
   }
   mean /= n;
double var = 0.0;
   for( i=0; i<n; ++i)
   {   
   double d = x[i] - mean;
       var += d*d;
   }
   var /= n;
```

or in one pass, eg

```
double mean = 0.0;
double var = 0.0;
  for( i=0; i<n; ++i)
  {  
  double f = 1.0/(i+1);
  double d = x[i]-mean;
      mean += d*f;
      var = (1.0-f)*(var + f*d*d);
  }
```

(it takes a bit of tedious algebra to show that the one pass method gives the same answer as the two pass method).